# Insert bullets in Microsoft Notepad

Tags: notepad

Is there any shortcut to insert 'bullet' character in Microsoft Notepad ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not just for Notepad, but for any application that can read ASCII special characters.

The bullet is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0149 (must have NumLock on and use the number pad). 
<sup>Source: [Help Pages – MS Keyboards – Standard English | Foreign Languages and Cultures | Washington State University](https://web.archive.org/web/20161216104623/https://forlang.wsu.edu/help-pages/microsoft-keyboards-standard-english-us101/)</sup>

It's probably easier to do it once, then copy and paste...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normally you can do a bullet • with [alt]+7 on numpad, but on WordPad these days you must use [alt]+0149.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind the simplest method is just to simply copy it from any MS Word or PowerPoint or somewhere else and paste it in Notepad, Like here:

[image]