# Insert bullets in TextEdit on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, textedit

i see this question : [Insert bullets in Micosoft Notepad](https://superuser.com/q/404223/124554)
so, i interested to know "shortkey to insert 'bullet' character in TextEdit"

Comment: Unless you're talking about MAC addresses, you probably mean Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> inserts a bullet or increases indentation level, and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> decreases indentation level. They only work in rich text mode though, and TextEdit always uses the `⁃` (HYPHEN BULLET) character for bullets.

Comment: Although the `-` character is used by default, after the indentation is changed, you can highlight the bullets and change the character using the "List bullets and numbering" drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>